# Linux Ubuntu 16.04 & nVidia GeForce 720M - Black Screen

Tags: nvidia

Yesterday, I did a fresh install of Linux Ubuntu 16.04. After that, I installed Gnome3. After that, I decided to use nVidia Binary Drivers and not nouveau since I had some screen flickering.

Tonight, I've got stucked on black screen which is showing after grub menu.

There's a light, monitor is working, but it's pure black.

I've Googled about this a lot recently. What I've tried:

Purging all nVidia packages and doing a fresh install of drivers and X server
Using "nomodeset" and deleting "splash" from GRUB
Updating initramfs
Removing all nVidia packages, then installing manually, a few versions of driver
I will provide any info you need, since I need my lap top tonight and I can't get it to work.

The lap top is ASUS X550VC, running Ubuntu 16.04. Graphic card is nVidia GeForce 720M.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graphics issues after installing Ubuntu 16.04 with NVIDIA graphics](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics)

Comment: None of those solutions helped. I also didn't said that it is a dual GPU lap top (Intel HD4000 is the other GPU). I would also go for a fresh install if someone can provide me with the steps on how to install nVidia driver without any errors.

Comment: Hmm. Does it work if you set `nouveau.modeset=0` in GRUB and boot without using any proprietary drivers?

Comment: I just purged nvidia* again, purged GNOME and installed nvidia-364. I will try to run it now with and withtou nouveau.modeset=0. Give me a second.

Comment: It looks like lightdm is failing to start. I've removed Gnome for sure now & I've got login screen with Ubuntu Desktop. However, I can't login. Error message: Failed to start session. In tty1, there's a message "A start job is running for monitor and control system power state".

Comment: make sure you actually have a desktop environment installed

Comment: I have it installed. I have Ubuntu Desktop. Okay, I won't get anywhere trying to fix this. Can you give me a full tutorials on how to install latest nVidia drivers on Ubuntu 16.04? I will do a fresh install of Ubuntu now. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The full tutorial is in the Q&A I linked. It's just different context

Comment: Yes, as I could see. However, I did all of that and that's how I came to these errors. Whatever I try, it's not working. :/

Comment: do the reinstall and try it

Comment: Okay, I will try now. May I comment this question if I get any errors again, so you can see it? Thanks, once again.

Comment: go ahead. Just put @Zacharee1 so I get a notification

Comment: @Zacharee1 Lol... I reinstalled Ubuntu, opened Additional Drivers, selected nVidia proprietary driver, clicked Apply Changes and rebooted... Working like a charm. Now, let's install some GUI and see if there are any errors. :)

Comment: @Zacharee1 And there's a problem. When I attached my other monitor, went to settings and made it primary... I've got black screens again. However, black screen are there only after log in.